# QprogressBar is jumping from 0 to 100 in a sec, how to make it smooth

Tags: c++, qt, post, progress-bar

Hi all I have problem with qprogressbar. How can I make it smooth? I want it to go smoothly from 0 to 100% . I am using it with reply variable which reads data from php script and returning me data. I need to wait 3-4 seconds to get my data I want that progressbar to go smoothly from 0 to 100 and I only have instantly from 0-100.

Here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::updateDataTransferProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)
{
    ui->progressBar->setMaximum(bytesTotal);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(bytesReceived);

}

void MainWindow::Citanje_korisnika()
{
    init();

    QUrl params;
        params.addQueryItem("action","Citanje_korisnika");

        QByteArray data;
        data.append(params.toString());
        data.remove(0,1);

        QNetworkRequest request;
        request.setUrl(url);
        request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
        QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        reply = manager->post(request, data);
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)),this, SLOT(updateDataTransferProgress(qint64,qint64)));

}
```

If you need more code..just tell me.

EDIT 2:
Here is my another part of code:

```
void MainWindow::init()
{
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/direkt_php_qt.php";
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
   // connect(manager, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)),this,SLOT(updateDataTransferProgress(qint64,qint64)));
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}
```

So program starts and first thing it goes into function`void MainWindow::Citanje_korisnika()` then it goes to `void MainWindow::init()` and then `void MainWindow::updateDataTransferProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)` problem is. I want to make this progress bar to go smoothly from the begginig of the program until he downloaded all data to my reply variable. 
Now I am getting my form shown and then I waint 3-4 sec nothing is happening, I see my progress bar at 0 and nothing is filled with data and then after some time progress bar jumpes to 100% and data is show.. So I want this perios while program is loading from server to see my progress bar going from 0-100 at some normal speed. Now I only see blank fileds and then boom everything is on. I want to make it all go smoothly. If you know what I mean.

Comment: I am getting XML from PHP script into the reply variable.

Comment: So you just want to wait three seconds before posting the request? Or do you want to wait three seconds before showing the data?

Comment: @denonth Well, this doesn't make your question a PHP question, I removed the tag. If you think it indeed to have something to do with the PHP script (which I doubt), then post it, mention it as an opportunity and feel free to readd the tag. And we might need to know what `reply` and `manager` are, although it may be obvious.

Comment: sure I have made my question more explained now

Comment: Add ui->ProgressBar->repaint().  A real fix is going to require a thread.

Comment: @denoth I'm not current with Qt's network layering, but my first guess is that you are seeing issues with threading and waiting for `manager->post(request, data);` to complete.  Have you tried putting a break point in `updateDataTransferProgress(...)` and then stepping through `Citanje_korisnika()` from the `post(..)` to the `connect(..)`?

Comment: I have never done threading. can somone give me clue how to make this work with threading? Because I think there is just to much time waiting on post varibale to get me results back..I can make this done in antother thread and meanwhile read progressbars values?

Comment: repaint is not working..everything is same

Comment: I don't see problem in such situation. Imho, progress bar smoothness is a last thing user would care about. Anyway, consider processing request result and displaying progress on that alongside with download progress.

Comment: Problem is. Bar is not doing what it should to. It just jumps from 0-100...I mean for that I don't need progress bar... I want to make it as download bar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like here the `bytesReceived == bytesTotal` and thats why its jumping from 0 to 100% immediately. If you know approximate size of `bytesTotal` you can set `QNetworkReply::setReadBufferSize(qint64 size)` to fraction of `bytesTotal`. Than at least you will some progress. However as mentioned in the docu this will throttle down your download speed and I see no point in that.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. How did you mean to put that size variable? I just read it and send it to bytesTotal? Can you give me simple example..Or you want me to do it in connect()?

Comment: Situation where `bytesReceived == bytesTotal` seems very likely. Also, pay attention to the fact that `bytesTotal` could also be 1 if `QNAM` was unable to query content's length.

Comment: But I don't get it..When it starts I need to wait 3-4 seconds..I think post method is taking that long and communication with server

Comment: Firstly, you querying `localhost` which is fast. Secondly, `downloadProgress` signal is not emitted after connection established. As [documentation says](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#downloadProgress): `This signal is emitted to indicate the progress of the download part`.

Comment: But basically I am downloading when executing post method, because I get some result back right?